# Editing multiple dynamically generated UITextFields at runtime

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitextfield, touch

I have made an application in which user may generate as many UITextField as he/she wants and those will be automatically placed over a UIView. Functionality is that user may drag the any of the UITextField at any point of screen.Till this part every thing is quite working. Now if he wants to edit the UITextField he taps(2 times) on UITextField and edits.This part of mine is only working for the recent generated UITextField not for all. How can i do this? I fnay one wants my previous code i can post. Plese respond it sonn. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
        add textFieldArray to .h file then specify <UITextFieldDelegate> and

        sythesize that array.


        while creating the each textfield

        specify delegate like this

        mytextF1.delegate=self;

        mytextF2.delegate=self;

        .....


        after that add all text field object to an textFieldArray which should be declared .h file and synthesize them .(dont forget to alloc and init this array in ur viewdidload).


        self.textFieldArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        then add each text field to this array

        [self.textFieldArray addObject:mytextF1];

        [self.textFieldArray addObject:mytextF2];

        .......

        then use this delegate methode to update

        - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{



            for (UITextField *textF in self.textFieldArray) {

                [textF setText:[textField text]];

            }



        }
```

Comment: Hey @Madhu Thanks for your response but the problem is that i can't define any array because the size of array can't be fixed as the textFields are being generated by the user at run time and we have not any fixed size. I have just implemented the delegate functions to edit but that is only working for the recent generated UITextField even when my touch is recognising the previous UITextFields.

Comment: whenever user  create textfield  then simply put that  [self.textFieldArray addObject:mytextF1]; .it will add and grows as many.so no worry about how many textfield created.

Comment: give me the more code about dynamic creation of textfield function i will resolve u

Comment: //This code is for generating the UItextFields dynamically!!
if(textGenerated)
{
textOnView=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,length*(sizeText),sizeText+10)];
  textOnView.text=text;
  textOnView.font=[UIFont fontWithName:font size:sizeText];
  textOnView.center=BackGround.center;
  [textOnView setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
  textOnView.delegate=self;
  [self.view addSubview:textOnView];
}